# How to create an HTML5 custom validation that check if the value inserted into 2 email inout field is the same?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I am pretty new in **HTML 5** and I have the following doubt.

I have a form like this:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="/IDES/salvaRegistrazione" method="POST" name="formRegistrazione">
    
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="inputNome">Nome</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input id="inputNome" class="form-control" type="text" value="" required="required" placeholder="Nome" name="nome">
        </div>
    </div>
        
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="inputEmail">E-mail</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input id="inputEmail" class="form-control" type="email" value="" required="required" placeholder="E-mail" name="email">
        </div>
   </div>
        
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="inputEmail2">E-mail</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input id="inputEmail2" class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Inserisci nuovamente E-mail" name="inputEmail2">
        </div>
    </div>  
        
    <input id="submitRegistrazione" class="btn btn-default pull-right" type="submit" value="Registrati" name="submitRegistrazione">
</form>
```

As you can see the input tag have setted the `required="required"` attribute and as you can see in this JSFiddle if you don't insert the value into the input tag it is automatically shown an HTML error message popup:

https://jsfiddle.net/fntwyn9j/

Now my problem is that into my form I have also 2 field having `type="email"`.

My problem is that I want that if the second email value (the one inserted in the field having `id="inputEmail2"`) is not equal to the first email value (the one inserted into the field having `id="inputEmail"`) appear a custom message (in the same HTML5 style) that say to me that the 2 fields have not the same value and the form is not submitted.

Searching on the web I found this example that use event listener to add custom message: http://jsfiddle.net/B4hYG/9/

But is seems to me that don't work and I have no idea about how to implement the previous requirement.

How can I solve this issue and implement this kind of HTML5 custom validation?

Answer (score 1):

Solved by myself:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    document.getElementById("inputEmail2").addEventListener("input", function (e) {

        valoreInpitEmail = $('#inputEmail').val();
        valoreInpitEmail2 = $('#inputEmail2').val();

        //alert("value inputEmail: " + valoreInpitEmail + " value inputEmail2: " + valoreInpitEmail2);

        //if (e.target.value != "") {
        if(valoreInpitEmail != valoreInpitEmail2) {
            alert("EMAIL DIVERSE");

            //alert("BLABLABLA");
            e.target.setCustomValidity("Le E-mail inserite non corrispondono, per favore inserirle nuovamente");
        }
        else {
            // Let the browser decide whether this is a valid email address
            // This actually prevents that the call of setCustomValidity()
            // in the IF doesn't get removed thus the user cannot submit the form
            //alert("ELSE");
            e.target.setCustomValidity("");
        }
    });
});
```